# Issue? Timestamp of files wrong on Kernel 5.4.x

Tags: kernel, 20.04

There may be a problem with Kernel 5.4.x in combination with external drives (in my case: microSD -card + card reader).

Files which are showing a correct timestamp under Linux 4.x and MacOS (Windows not tested yet), show a shifted timestamp under Linux 5.4.x (tested with Ubuntu and Armbian).

Most files differ by 2685599 seconds (approx. 31 days).

This effect seems to be independent from the content creating device (e.g. camera).

I would appreciate if someone could test this out and let me know.

Steps to reproduce:

1. create file on camera (video or photo)
2. mount (micro-)SD card under Kernel 4.x (e.g. Ubuntu 18) and check timestamps
3. mount card under Kernel 5.4.x (e.g. Ubuntu 20) and check timestamps again.